# Installing Elementary Isis beta

Tags: linux, elementary-os

How can I install Elementary OS Isis Beta?

I tried to made a bootable stick using the latest [iso builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eosbuilds/files/isis-unstable/) but for some reason I cannot login.

Having elementary OS installed on my machine, how can I update every day to the latest build?

I want to update to elementary OS Isis and to be up-to-date even it is unstable.

Comment: Are you using this as a bootable OS from USB or did you install it to a hard drive?

Comment: @Brian I already have Luna on my machine, but I would like to know both solutions (installing from bootable device and via a command).

Comment: While I'm not sure how to help with the login, you might (I haven't tested it) use this PPA to help keep it up to date: https://launchpad.net/elementaryos/0.3-isis

Comment: @Brian Post an answer and I will try.